# Two columns and one footer divided by Border (Individual sides) using css

Tags: css

I want to create a robust css style that works whith almost all browser (included IE7, firefox 3)
that show me two columns and  one footer divided by dotted border.
I was trying to implement the following code,
but I have one problem: 
when I apply border-right-style:dotted; to left class
A and B are not at the same horizontal level.
please halp me to fix the css style.

[Click here for the current example](http://jsfiddle.net/euYTQ/15/).

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div clas="left">A</div>
  <div class="right">B</div>
  <div class="footer">C</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.container {
    background:#eee;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 750px;
} 
.left{
    background:#ddd;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    border-right-style:dotted;
}
.right {
    background:#eee;
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}
.footer {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #eef;
    clear: both;
    border-top-style:dotted;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that you're experiencing is that the border of the element is not contained within the defined width of that element; so the element is 50% of its parents width, but with an additional width added by the border.

If you reduce the width of the elements to, for example, 48%, then it seems to work as you'd like:

```
div.container {
    background:#eee;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 750px;
} 
.left{
    background:#ddd;
    float: left;
    width: 48%;
    border-right-style:dotted;
}
.right {
    background:#eee;
    float: right;
    width: 48%;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/euYTQ/23/).

---

**Edited** with update,

You could, for Firefox and Chromium (FF5.x and Chromium 12.x on Ubuntu 11.04) use:

```
div {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box; /* Left this in, but it doesn't seem to work... */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/euYTQ/29/).

Which incorporates the border width into the width of the element; with this approach you could retain the `width: 50%;` on the elements and borders would sort themselves out. Unfortunately it doesn't work on Opera or, presumably, IE.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed

http://jsfiddle.net/euYTQ/19/

What you've got to remember is that a border counts + of the % assigned.

So say you have a box thats 100px's wide (100%), and you put one side with a 1px border (1%), thats actually 101%. So in your case, it was breaking to the next line of space, hence giving you your error.

In my fix i simply set the right container to 49%. Which would be great for fluid solutions, or if you have a fixed layout, set it to a fixed value.

Remember, padding is the same too... it will count + of the assigned size or percent.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The reason A and B are on different levels is because they don't fit into one width.  You have them each declared with `width: 50%` but one of the also has a border.  Border width is added to the width of the div - thus the two divs plus the border don't fit into horizontal spacing.

For example, try putting `width: 49%` on each of them - and you'll see the difference.  This is not ideal, as you don't always know the width of the viewport.  If you can work with exact pixel widths, it would be easier.  Try this CSS for a change:

```
div.container {
    background:#eee;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 750px;
} 
.left{
    background:#ddd;
    float: left;
    width: 374px;
    border-right:dotted 2px black;
}
.right {
    background:#eee;
    float: right;
    width: 374px;
}
.footer {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #eef;
    clear: both;
    border-top-style:dotted;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `50%` + `50%` + `1px`(the border) is higher than `100%`.
If your `.container` isn't going to change width's you could give them both a fixed pixel value.

However if your `.container` is going to change width's you could try adding another element that contains the border alone like so:

```
.border {
    height:100%;
    width:0;
    border-left:3px dotted #000;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:0;
}
```

Don't forget to give `.container` a `position:relative;`.

Answer (score 1):

@Antojs; `padding & border` add width to the element if the element in percentage it's create problem. So; can give width to one like this:

```
div.container {
    background:#eee;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 750px;
}
.left{
    background:#ddd;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    border-right-style:dotted;
}
.right {
    background:#eee;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Now in `.right` if you give `border & padding` it's not effect anything & you can also use css3 `box-sizing: border-box;` but it's not supported by IE7

check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/euYTQ/30/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the border adds width to the `div` with `.left`. As the container `div` appears to be of fixed width, you could simply give the `.left` and `.right` elements fixed width values too (or reduce their percentage widths), and make `.left` slightly narrower:

```
.left{
    background:#ddd;
    float: left;
    width: 372px;
    border-right-style:dotted;
}
.right {
    background:#eee;
    float: right;
    width: 375px;
}
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/euYTQ/21/). I would also suggest reading up on the [box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html) to get an idea of how borders, padding etc. add on to width.

Comment: I wouldn't say this is what AntonJs was looking for as they using % not fixed unit of measurement

Comment: @Alistair - As the container `div` was of fixed width, I thought this may be acceptable. I did also mention the fact that he could simply lower the percentage widths.

Comment: Sorry you quiet right the container did have a fixed width and you did mention percentages. [been a long week]

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/euYTQ/18/

50% and 50% = 100% so no space for the border.

Answer (score 0):

Put your div right in the div left

```
 <div class="left">section left
        <div class="right">section right</div>
    </div>
```

and change a little the css

```
.left{
    background:#ddd;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;       
}
.right {
    background:#eee;
    float: right;
     border-left-style:dotted;  
}
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/euYTQ/28/